# What attracts cells to: pathogens, professional antigen-presenting cells, and cells with an antigen on its MHC-1 protein?

Tags: immunology, antibody, antibiotics, antigen

I have a few questions in regards to attraction/stimulation in the immune system.

1. What attracts leukocytes and antibodies to pathogens in the first place?
2. What attracts CD4+ cells to professional antigen-presenting cells (APC)?
3. What attracts CD8+ cells to cells with an antigen on a MHC-1 protein?
4. What attracts macrophages to pathogens that have been tagged with antibodies?

Is it just a case of everything bumping into each other and if cells (and antibodies??) bump into chemokines and/or cytokines they will be stimulated (and not attracted) to stay around that area moving to an area of a greater concentration of chemokines and/or cytokines?

That said point 1 can occur without chemokines and/or cytokines (in the case of antibodies, they could be taken/administered by the person).  While in case of point 3, (I may be wrong here) but chemokines and/or cytokines may not be present in the case of MHC-1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What attracts leukocytes and antibodies to pathogens in the first
>   place?

They just bump into them. If secreted antibody is already present in the blood then complement system can be activated.

> What attracts CD4+ cells to professional antigen-presenting cells
>   (APC)?

APC release chemokines. All that is known is that this is a CC-type chemokine and signals via CCR4/CCR8 receptors. See [this list](http://scholar.google.co.in/scholar?q=antigen+presenting+cells+chemotaxis+chemokine&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart&sa=X&ei=szfOU9aeFpajugS4vYLABg&ved=0CBkQgQMwAA) of articles (from Google Scholar). [This](http://jem.rupress.org/content/198/7/977.abstract) study reports a peptide called Chemrin that promotes chemotaxis via ChemR23 receptor.

> What attracts CD8+ cells to cells with an antigen on a MHC-1 protein?

CD8+/NK cells are activated by CD4+ cells before they kill their target. The MHC-1+antigenic peptide is just a mark for the cells that are to be attacked, as far as I understand.

> What attracts macrophages to pathogens that have been tagged with
>   antibodies?

[Complement factors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_system).

NOTE: Many of these concepts are old but still relevant. You should check out recent articles in this area for novel/atypical mechanisms.

Comment: Regarding the answer to the first question: yes, if we are talking about circulating pathogens. But if the pathogen has cytotoxic effects on a tissue, the release of damaged cell components may attract immune system cells by chemotaxis.

Comment: yeah forgot to add that.. Cells can release type-1 interferons.

Comment: Brilliant, thank-you! I've been reading up on the self non-self theory & the danger theory..So was trying to arduously identify some of the danger signals that were already present.  And thank-you @Cornelius