# What's the procedure of the antigen recognition by the B cells in a clear way?

Tags: immunology

Before presenting my confusion, I really sincerely thank everyone for any advices or clarifying , every  single comment  is helpful.  And my english writing skill is still very bad, Just ask anything if you are confused.
I have first referenced JaneWay's immunobiology textbook and [this question about roughly the same question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/19852/what-attracts-cells-to-pathogens-professional-antigen-presenting-cells-and-ce).
However, the exact process is still not very clear in my mind.
So for clearance, Let's imagine the entire  process at the beginning, that is, the time a pathogen having already successfully invade to our body and start circulating throughout blood vessel.
So **the first question**: The antigen could be distinguished into two types, one of which we have already identified and one of which is totally new to our body,is this understanding correct?
Then, **the second question**:for the identified pathogen, our antibody which is circulating throughout our body will somehow bind the pathogen and triggers a series of immune response, is this understanding correct?
And then **The third and seems like the most untrivial question**: for the antigen which is totally new (didn't remembered by our immune cells) to our body, **How does our cell knows it is at the first place indeed a pathogen?**
Just give me some references  will be enormously helpful for me, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't pull resources for you at this time, and my response is too long for a comment, but just to give you some direction to research:

Firstly, if you are not clear, I would try to understand how antigen and pathogen are different terms. Understanding "epitope" and "hapten" may also help with your understanding.

1. Yes, **BUT** it's less "type of antigen" and more "state of immune system" - either there is immunologic memory [to the particular antigen] or there is not.
2. Yes, there is an antibody binding domain on the variable region of the antibody. Keywords: "Fc/Fab, Constant region/Variable region, Heavy chain/Light chain, V(D)J recombination, CDR1/2/3."
3. It does not "know." Ideally, it recognizes all foreign particles (of sufficient immunogenicity) as "antigens," but this process is not perfect. Common examples of "improper" recognition are autoimmune disorders and allergies. Try looking into T/B Cell Maturation/Activation, Thymus cells, and B Cell Dual Recognition (the classic/dominant method of activation in response to pathogenic infection). I think this will give you a better understanding of how the body *tries* to limit its immune response to what we consider "pathogenic."

If the question doesn't get locked, hopefully someone can provide a more complete response to you.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but if let's say if our innate immune system will automatically attack those pathogens which has "Pathogen-associated molecular pattern" PAMPs, then why does those benign bacteria living in our guts doesn't get attacked by our immune system?

Comment: I don't think it is well known and upon cursory search, appears to be an area of active research. The question warrants a separate post.